# junit: how to avoid false positives when using forkMode="once"?

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, junit, false-positive

I'd like to speed up junit tests and I think about using `forkMode="once"`.

Due to the fact that junit [seems to use a shared classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254965/junit-impact-of-forkmode-once-on-test-correctness) for all tests within one process beside false negatives (which is good thing because it exposes static coupling) there might be also false positives by the same reason.

I've got **two questions** regarding this:

1. Is it somehow possible to alter the classloader behavior in junit to **enforce a new classloader for each test case**? I think it would be ideal to be able to run junit in both mdoes to avoid both false positives and negatives.
2. Is it easily possible to **randomize test order** to decrease the probability of false positives (using ant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know what you want is not supported, but in any case, I think you should reconsider your approach: you should make your code more testable so it will not depend on a new JVM/Classloader.

But if you can't/won't - your best course of action is to fork.

Comment: You're right, my code shouldn't be tied to a new jvm/classloader. This is exactly what I am trying to archive. However, because of false positives I may not realize that tests are tied together and I will get the illusion that everything alright - until a run the problematic tests individually (or the customer complains)

Comment: You should try to make your tests assert the starting point of your tests is correct.

Comment: RonK, I disagree.  That's a lot of repetitive code for every Test class you write (we have hundreds of legacy tests we're not going to rewrite).  This is something the framework could/should do for you.